# Is it possible to die from overwork?

Tags: public-health

There have been several claims that people will die from overwork like Miwa Sado[1](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/oct/05/japanese-woman-dies-overwork-159-hours-overtime) this is related to overwork but death came from suicide. 
Gamers are like Brian Vigneault[2](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2017/02/23/va-man-died-during-marathon-attempt-to-play-video-game-for-24-hours/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.5f3522795bf3) which died after 24h of gaming which seems health related. Is it possible to work till you die of exhaustion, wouldn't the body colapse into sleep before?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kar%C5%8Dshi, An otherwise healthy would probably not die from a single instance of overwork, though.

Comment: Death from exertion alone isn't found many mammals, some exceptions sort of are antechinus and some other marsupials.

Comment: From exhaustion? Yes. From "work"? It depends on how you define work. Dying while playing video games is not caused by overwork, but from a myriad of factors.